# Load internal module attribute with WebPack

Tags: javascript, webpack, dojo, webpack-loader

I'm porting an old Dojo Toolkit application to newer technologies (Vue.js and WebPack).

#### My scenarios is...

Those new modules should work with old Dojo Loader or the new WebPack loader. I was able to remove most of dojo dependencies but I still need to use the plugins dojo/text (which loads a html file as a string) and dojo/i18n (which loads a module based on the locale) for the new components.

Those components are being prototyped on a WebPack application but on production it will still use Dojo Loader util all Dojo dependencies was removed.

I was able to configure WebPack to load the HTML when using dojo/text and the default language when using dojo/i18n using:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^dojo\/text!/, function(data) {
    data.request = data.request.replace(/^dojo\/text!/, '!html-loader!');
  }),
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^dojo\/i18n!/, function(data) {
    data.request = data.request.replace(/^dojo\/i18n!/, '');
  })
]
```

#### The issue...

A typical i18n Dojo module for the default language is:

```
define({
  root: {
    placeholder: 'Name'
  },
  es: true,
  pt: true
});
```

Dojo loader get only the **root** attribute as the module result:

```
define({
  placeholder: 'Name'
});
```

#### The question is...

Can I load a module, parse or eval it and return just the root attribute as result, using a existing loader or plugin?

Making this module:

```
define({
  root: {
    placeholder: 'Name'
  },
  es: true,
  pt: true
});
```

be transformed into

```
define({
  placeholder: 'Name'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, a custom loader can be writen, the source code of the loader is:

```
module.exports = function(source) {
  return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(eval('function define(x) { return x; }; ' + source).root);
};
```

And you must include use `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` do add the loader:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^dojo\/i18n!/, function(data) {
  data.request = data.request.replace(/^dojo\/i18n!/, '!dojo-i18n!');
})
```